# Best way to find an element behind a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

(edited the question per Frits van Campens comment)

I'm trying to sort out the best way to find an element behind a clicked element--as if the element behind was the intended target but there is an element on top of it.

As example, I have a div, that when clicked has some styling (a border) applied via a :before pseudo class. Unfortunately the :before element blocks clicks on child elements (since it's the same size as the containing div).

Is there a good way to get the child element or ignore clicks on the :before element?

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks! -Ted

Comment: This sound like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - please tell us about X, not Y.

Comment: I'm sure you are not doing it as it should, but i'm not sure what 'it' is. Anyway, maybe you are just looking for pointer-events CSS rule setted to none.

Comment: "pointer-events CSS rule setted to none" -- Thanks A. Wolff, that did the trick exactly! (I'll edit the original post to be specifically about the problem).